# Maven - deal with DLLs

Tags: java, maven, dll, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm new in Maven and I can't figure out how to deal with DLLs.

I managed to create a jar-with-dependencies that contains the jar-dependencies inside and the jars are find. However for the DLL part I don't know. When executing, I got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no NCore in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.neurotec.lang.NCore.<clinit>(NCore.java:128)
```

But I don't know how and where put DLLs:

- inside the jar itself
- outside (if yes, how to specify the java.library.path)

My DLLs are currently stored under src/main/ressources/win32-amd64/*.dll.
And Maven actually put this directory at the root of the jar.

What should I do? :)

Here's an extract of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Djava.library.path=target/classes/win32-amd64/</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>gui.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

As you can see, I also tried to specify the library.path using surefire, pointing to the classes/win32-amd64 folder but ...

Thank you in advance :)